# Noob Question: Can't find my skeleton after upating to 2.9

Tags: armature

So I've had Blender for years now but I'm still a noob at it. I made a bipedal model, an armature, and weight-painted it in Blender 2.7. I then figured it was about time to update it to 2.9. After I did that, I can't see my armature anymore! I have tried Unhiding everything with Alt-H, clicking around the Outline, toggling the X-Ray for the mesh, fidding with Viewport Display settings in Properties, but nothing seems to be working. It is such a simple thing yet I've spent literally an hour trying to figure it out, and I am getting really frustrated with myself. Thank you for your help!

The armature I want to be visible is Penguin>Skeleton

[image: Blender 2.7 where the skeleton is visible]

[image: Blender 2.9 where I can't find the skeleton]

Edit: Here is a link to my .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1darEP59YbALtv4lqDqYXXS6K270zA3_n/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you turned on the **in front** option from the visibility? Or maybe attach your .blend file

Comment: I think so. I've shared the file to Google Drive here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1darEP59YbALtv4lqDqYXXS6K270zA3_n/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's disabled in the viewport. select it in the outliner, enable disable viewport filter, and switch it back on -

[image]

Comment: OK, so I selected the Armature in the Outliner, enabled the Disable in Viewport Filter, and switched it back on for the Armature. But, I still can't see my skeleton for some reason? Even when I hide my mesh, I still cannot see the skeleton?

Comment: OK so I somehow accidentally solved the problem. Thank you for your help!